# Мне нужно сравнить два char '"' ( ' " ' без пробелов ) и '\"' ( ' \ " ' без пробелов ), чтобы результатом сравнения было False

Tags: c#

Как сравнить два символа, обычный , и этот же экранированный символ, сравнивая через == возвращается false, а мне нужно отделить их

Comment: Перепишите вопрос так, чтобы данные оказались в теле вопроса, а не в заголовке. Пока ничего не понятно. И переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы стало понятно, где там `false`, и что вам нужно.

Comment: Для чего вам это надо? Ну написали вы `\"` и `"`, на выходе ведь будет одно, ибо это один символ, у них один код, да и все остальное одинаковое. Просто первый вариант экранирован, чтобы "машина" не запуталась и выдала вам верный результат, но для чего вам "детектить" экранирование, вот это уже вопрос... который мягко намекает на то, что вы делаете что-то не то...

Comment: `"` может быть char'ом, а `\"` уже нет, так как это уже два char'а. С чем Вам нужно их сравнивать? Опишите задачу и желательно проблему более подробно.

Comment: @XelaNimed А чего не понятного в задаче? Вроде все очевидно и понятно, у автора есть что-то на подобие [этого](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HOYDOX), он хочет, чтоб выдавало `false`, ибо `second` имеет экранирование, которое он и хочет определить.